# SQL Server: voiding all records but one per set with message

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `TableA (ID int, [set] int,[status] char(20), message char(20))`

```
ID set status message
1   1
2   1  MATCH
3   3
4   3  MATCH
5   2
6   2
```

Now I want to do two things here:

Set `status` = 'void'`where it is not 'match' in the same set. So`ID` with 1 and 3 will get the 'void'.

Set `message = "For ID = xx"` where `xx` is `ID`. Set the message where it is void also pointing to its corresponding matched ID.

I also want to `NULL the status and message for sets that do not contain a status of 'Match'`

Expected result:

```
ID set status message
1   1  VOID   For ID = 2
2   1  MATCH  NULL
3   3  VOID   For ID = 4
4   3  MATCH  NULL
5   2  NULL   NULL
6   2  NULL   NULL
```

Comment: I cant get around with this logic, I assume with CTE ?

Comment: Also I guess it has to be handled set by set. not in one go because of the message that I have to put !

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by a "match" - I see no difference between ID 1 and 2. Is it that the ID is the same as the set? But then what about 5 and 6 - they don't match, yet you didn't write match next to them.

Comment: There is another logic with updated the status as matched. (joins from other tables) So to simplify, I started off from 'MATCH'. Also there are other columns which are not discussed here because they play no role in THIS logic ! thanks

Comment: Does each "set" have two and only two rows?

Comment: no it could have more than two but only one "match" for the same set. Lets say set 5 has IDs 50 to 60 but only one say 55 has "match" all others get voided saying "for ID = 55"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Final solution

A different set of assumptions as my first one was missing the point:

- `TableA.ID` is unique.
- Some rows are marked as 'MATCH' to begin with, *never* more than one per set.
- Mark all other rows of the same set as 'VOID' and point to 'MATCH' in `message`.
- Set `status` and `message` to `NULL` for all rows in sets without a 'MATCH'.

```
;WITH s AS (
      SELECT [set]
            ,'VOID' AS stat
            ,('FOR ID = ' + CAST (ID AS char)) AS msg
      FROM   TableA
      WHERE  status = 'MATCH'
  )
UPDATE TableA
SET    status  = s.stat
      ,message = s.msg
FROM   s
WHERE  TableA.status IS NULL
AND    (s.[set] = TableA.[set] OR s.[set] IS NULL)
```

I have prepared a **working demo** for the new assumptions you on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/117980/demo-for-bhupinder-singh)

- Prepare the reduced set with ready-made `message` once in a CTE.
- JOIN the CTE into the UPDATE, but allow `[set]` to be `NULL` as well.
- Use explicit `cast` to convert integer to char.
- Use square brackets for reserved word `set`.
  I would advise not to use reserved words as identifiers.

This should deliver optimum performance.

---

#### Voided solution (wrong assumptions)

- `TableA.ID` is unique
- You want the *greatest ID per set* to be the 'MATCH' and all others to be 'VOID', regardless of the pre-UPDATE state of `status` and `message`.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET    status  = CASE ID WHEN x.max_id THEN 'MATCH' ELSE 'VOID' END
      ,message = CASE ID WHEN x.max_id THEN NULL
                         ELSE 'FOR ID = ' + CAST (x.max_id AS char) END
FROM   (
    SELECT [set]
          ,max(ID) AS max_id
    FROM   TableA
    GROUP  BY [set]
    ) AS x
WHERE  x.[set] = TableA.[set]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But unfortunately, it is not working accurately. It is updating [status] as 'Match' even for the rows that are not and hence the [message]. I guess It is matching all MAX(ID) in the same [set].

Comment: @BhupinderSingh: Can you help me understand this: `It is updating [status] as 'Match' even for the rows that are not and hence the [message].`? Please define which rows should be updated exactly and which "are not"? Edit your question with the information rather than in a lengthy comment.

Comment: Erwin: [status] = match is populated from another query. So the situation we have here is: Find the status = match. set void for the same set. and put the message for the corresponding ID. We are not supposed to populated "match" in this update process. That has already been taken care of.

Comment: Please take a look at my query: It is working when I have only one match. but for this example, it is returning more than one value for ID please correct.

Comment: So as to your assumption, yes, ID is unique but Match can be at max or min or anywhere so we have to pick up the ID where status = 'match'

Comment: @BhupinderSingh:  Please see my amended answer. I think this should finally do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a copy of SQL Server right now, but it is something like this.  Two update statements, one for the matching rows, and one for the non-matching rows.

```
update tablea
   set message = null
 where status = 'MATCH'

update a1
   set a1.message = 'For ID = ' + CAST((select a2.id 
                                       from tablea a2
                                      where a2.status = 'MATCH'
                                        and a2.set = a1.set) AS NVARCHAR(20))
      ,a1.status = 'VOID'
  from tablea a1
 where a1.status <> 'MATCH' 
    or a1.status is null
```

Comment: This looks to be close, but I do not see you `NULL`ing the status and message columns for sets with no 'Match' status

Comment: @AdamWenger I can add another update statement for that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on SQL Server, and it should be what you need, minor tweaks if a different flavor of SQL.

```
UPDATE ta
SET ta.status = CASE
                  WHEN ta.status = 'Match' THEN 'Match'
                  ELSE NULL
                END
   , ta.message = null
FROM TableA AS ta
WHERE ta.status = 'Match'
   OR ta.[set] NOT IN
   (
      SELECT ita.[set]
      FROM TableA AS ita
      WHERE ita.status = 'Match'
      GROUP BY ita.[set]
   )

UPDATE ta
SET ta.status = 'Void'
   , ta.message = 'For ID = ' + CAST(v.Id AS VARCHAR(5))
FROM TableA AS ta
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT id, [set]
   FROM TableA AS ta
   WHERE ta.status = 'Match'
) AS v ON ta.[set] = v.[set]
   AND ta.Id != v.Id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code but unfortunately it is not working. It is neither populating [status] nor [message].

Answer (score 0):

```
update tablea set [message] = 
(case  when (select top 1 id from TableA t2
             where t2.status = 'MATCH' and t2.[set] = t1.[set]) > 0
 then 'For ID = ' + convert(nvarchar(max), 
                    (select top 1 id from TableA t2
                     where t2.status = 'MATCH' and t2.[set] = t1.[set]))
  else 'void'
  end) 
from TableA t1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working only when I have one match but for this example, it is returning more than 1 IDs. All suggestions to improve this would be appreciated !! Thanks

```
update tableA
set [status] = 'VOID'
from tableA
where status is null 
and [set] in  (select [set] from tableA where status = 'Matched' )

DECLARE @matchID bigint
     SET @MatchID =  (SELECT ID FROM tableA WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE status = 'Match')


update tableA 
set [[message] = '<forID =' + CAST (@matchID as VARCHAR(15))
from tableA
where status = 'void' 
and [set] in  (select [set] from tableA where status = 'Match' )
```